# Alias in subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain, mod-alias

i want to create an alias in my subdomain.
The easiest way to do for my host is this :

```
Alias "/docs" "/var/sudomain/web"
```

Here all requests from http://google.io/docs will use folder /var/sudomain/web

but i want to do this

```
Alias "subdomain/docs" "/var/web"
```

Here all requests from http://subdomain.google.io/docs will use folder /var/sudomain/web

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! This question is being voted for closure because the author does not show a level of technical understanding or appropriate due diligence in researching the topic that the community judges as being a minimum barrier to participate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subdomain` is part of the hostname, not part of the path.

The normal way to do this would be to have a separate `<VirtualHost ...>` block that has the hostname.  That virtualhost would contain something like

```
ServerName subdomain.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/web/wherever
Alias "/docs" "/var/subdomain/web"
```

Otherwise, you might be able to use `mod_rewrite` to get part of the hostname into the path somehow.